# Why does scipy.optimize.minimize not find the minimum?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy-optimize

I am looking to find for which (x) the following function is minimal given a parameter dim.
This is the function:

```
def func(x, dim):
    return np.abs(np.abs(np.mean(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.diff(
        np.random.rand(100000,dim,2)/x, axis=2)**2, axis=1))))
        - 1/3)
```

And this is how it looks:

```
for xx in np.arange(1,5,0.1):
    plt.scatter(xx, func(xx,2), color='blue')
```

[image]

But when I try to find the x value which should be around 1.5 the result very close to my x0 guess (here around 1.0).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize


params = minimize(func, x0=1, args=(2))
```

I also tried different solvers, but I cannot get it to minimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to be deterministic for the minimization to work. So you need to remove your call to `np.random.rand`. Once solution could be to generate those random numbers once at the beginning and fix them throughout the minimization.

Comment: I though averaging over a large number of cases via np.mean would reduce this effect.

Comment: having said that, adding     np.random.seed(42) in the function solved it